# Drools UI + Spring boot + Angular.js integration

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

Is there any way to integrate `Drools UI` with Spring boot and angular.js application?

My requirement is I want drools UI to be integrated with my  UI app using angular.js so that I am able to create rules dynamically and execute them using spring boot code.

I was looking at `Guvnor` but realized that Guvnor is no more supported and it has been moved to `KIE`.

I would like to know weather is it feasible to integrate the Drools UI in my angular.js + Spring boot app.

Leads appreciated!

Comment: Angular or angularjs?

Comment: Basically our UI is developed using angular.js 7. I am looking forward if there is any way to integrate the Drools UI (Guvnor or Drools UI) with this. Rest API's are behind the scene built using Spring boot.